# How to pass linked services parameters to data flow from pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a source on Data Flow where I want to use a parameter to make a dynamic endpoint, I want to set the endpoint value from the data pipeline, I'm using a parameter created on the linked service but I didn't not found how is the appropriate way to set the value to that parameter from the pipeline.

[image]

I tried to create a parameter on the dataflow and set the linked service parameter default value pointed to data flow parameter but it was not successful.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

1. create a parameter in the linked service as you do.

[image]

2. create a parameter in the dataset and pass it's value to the parameter in the linked service.

[image]

[image]

3. create a parameter in your pipeline and set the default value.

[image]

4. pass the value from pipeline's parameter to your dataset in the setting of Data Flow.

[image]